# D3-request retrieval of a google spreadsheet csv/json file fails

Tags: d3.js, google-sheets, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, d3-request

I have difficulties to make Google spreadsheet and D3js' [D3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) / [D3-request > header](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#request_header) works together via xhr requests.

I use the following JS :

```
d3.request(url)
    .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    .mimeType("text/csv")
    .get(function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log('request: '+ data);
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSZyV9olwK_hx0BRFgLtTz5hs_Z…mROYhax3VD9AFXTvmcataf8LuSIpxGT2/pub?gid=1023695213&single=true&output=csv. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

[Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/97dqtssn/4/)

Any idea to bypass it ?

Comment: Please don't use emails from people without their consent for your sample data.

Comment: Oups. lets neutralise this quickly !

Comment: @MaximilianPeters : big thanks. I've been so much on this code that I forgot I had emails on my sheet.

Answer (score 1):

**Using D3 only**

```
d3.json(url, function (error, result) {
    var data = [];
    for (i = 0; i < result.feed.entry.length; i += 1) {
        data.push({
            "animal": result.feed.entry[i].gsx$animal.$t,
            "population": result.feed.entry[i].gsx$population.$t
        });
    }
    pie_chart(data, "#chart1");
});
```

**Using jQuery**

```
$.get(url, function (result) {
    var data = [];
    $(result.feed.entry).each(function () {
        data.push({"animal": this.gsx$animal.$t, "population": this.gsx$population.$t});
    });
    pie_chart(data, "#chart2");
});
```

**Using [tabletop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop).**

```
Tabletop.init({
    key: key,
    callback: function (data, tabletop) {
        pie_chart(data, "#chart3");
    },
    simpleSheet: true
});
```

---

Below is just a simple example to get data from a Google spreadsheet and turn it into a D3 [pie chart](https://jsfiddle.net/ragingsquirrel3/qkHK6/).

```js
//draws a pie chart with D3
function pie_chart(data, id) {
    var w = 400;
    var h = 400;
    var r = h / 2;
    var color = d3.scale.category20c();

    var vis = d3.select(id).append("svg:svg").data([data]).attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
    var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function (d) {
        return d.population;
    });
    var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

    var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "slice");
    arcs.append("svg:path")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
            return color(i);
        })
        .attr("d", function (d) {
            return arc(d);
        });

    arcs.append("svg:text").attr("transform", function (d) {
        d.innerRadius = 0;
        d.outerRadius = r;
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    }).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function (d, i) {
        return data[i].animal;
    });
}

//the key of google spreadsheet
var key = "1moczdbrfFwCp0L4Ube1a4GevuDcj2XQmCnpjArF_UEY";

//the url for jQuery and D3
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + key + "/od6/public/values?alt=json";

var i = 0;

//D3 only
d3.json(url, function (error, result) {
    var data = [];
    for (i = 0; i < result.feed.entry.length; i += 1) {
        data.push({
            "animal": result.feed.entry[i].gsx$animal.$t,
            "population": result.feed.entry[i].gsx$population.$t
        });
    }
    pie_chart(data, "#chart1");
});

//Jquery
$.get(url, function (result) {
    var data = [];
    $(result.feed.entry).each(function () {
        data.push({"animal": this.gsx$animal.$t, "population": this.gsx$population.$t});
    });
    pie_chart(data, "#chart2");
});

//tabletop

Tabletop.init({
    key: key,
    callback: function (data, tabletop) {
        pie_chart(data, "#chart3");
    },
    simpleSheet: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabletop.js/1.4.3/tabletop.js"></script>

<div id="chart1" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><span>D3 only</span></div>
<hr>
<div id="chart2" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><span>Jquery</span></div>
<hr>
<div id="chart3" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><span>Tabletop</span></div>
```

---

Comment: Hello Max. I'am not a fan of tabletopjs anymore. I actually spent 3 hours today on it to eventually find that [tabletopjs' readme.md is outdated and misleading](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop/issues/132). Also, I would like to get my hands on something more versatile, with more power and flexibility. D3-request seems promising if I can get how it works. Yet, thanks for tabletopjs code, it may help other budies :)

Comment: Thanks for that JQuery, it will help some users surely :)
(I'am looking for a D3-request solution tho)

Comment: Do you mean you do master D3-request but doesn't think it possible ? I was thinking setting d3-request header will be enough, but I may miss understood the situation. [D3-request > header](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#request_header)

Comment: O.ô ... I was not successful to do D3 + google sheet JSON. Could you open an other answer ? JSON satisfy my requirement : D3 + google spreadsheet working together.

Comment: This is VERY frustrating. I've now managed to narrow it down to the fact that my sheet is served without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` but your is served with. Any suggestions?

Comment: @pufferfish: Please open a new question with more details and I'm sure there is someone with a solution.